# Can I mount an electrical box on a non-stationary surface?

Tags: electrical

I am setting up a small rack panel and I'm mounting it to 1" ply on a piano hinge to make it easier to get behind.

I'd like to attach the electrical box on the same board. This means that the electric box could move but it won't be very often.

I was thinking I would use a stranded whip to connect the one on the board to a stationary box nearby.

Can I mount an electrical box to something that moves? In CA, USA.

Comment: What kind of power are we talking about? Standard 120v 15/20a, or something more heavy duty?

Comment: Is this something you're only going to be opening occasionally for maintenance?  Would it be possible to keep the hinges closed using a screw, instead of just a latch?  In that case, I don't even think you need to consider it movable -- every electrical box can be moved for maintenance by unscrewing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, we use flexible conduit all the time. If flex conduit is installed for flexibility it is limited to 6’ in length. I would suggest stranded conductors for longer life but code is not specific on that. metal flex is handy and industrial plants do just what you want to do routinely it is code compliant so FMT or flexible metal tubing (usually just called metal flex).

Comment: Actually I should have provided the article 360 . All the flexible conduit forms state where not subject to physical damage but also state accessible so this has always allowed them to be used in areas that required schedule 80 or rigid metal.

Comment: Can I use regular MC cable for this or is flex conduit necessary?

Comment: MC can be used but it is limited to 3’ where flexibility is required I don’t use MC often because the limit of 10 awg wire and no more than 4 conductors. I can check some more modern books tomorrow I want to say it has to be the interlocking type but that might be for light fixtures or pendant light fixtures. Again not subject to physical damage but as I mentioned flex and accessibility issues will have purest of the code objecting but there are photos of different types that break this rule in the code book so if it was 4 or less conductors 10 awg or smaller I would use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you "can" do that are pretty safe, but not strictly code-compliant. If you wanted to be as correct as possible, but maybe not 100% code compliant, you could install a fixed outlet box at a convenient location and then use a outlet/plug combination to get you to your movable outlet. You'd want to use type S or SJ or SO cable which is suited for movement.   Now I'm not saying this is code compliant, but should be a safe approach.  If anybody wants to snip me for suggesting a not strictly code compliant solution, go ahead and I'll learn something!

Comment: We can’t use SO or corded devices like this but that doesn’t mean it doesn’t get used. In fact if you look at code liquid tight flexible metal conduit is not allowed where subject to physical damage but in some plants you will only see liquid tight used but flexible metal tubing is allowed.